# Trying to turn a column into a row (SQL MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have an ODBC-sourced table in MS Access. It looks something like:

```
submit_time   | field_order | form_name     | field_name     | field_value    | file
xxxxxxxx                  0   Registration    from_email       xx@hotmail.com
xxxxxxxx                  1   Registration    name_to          Webmaster
xxxxxxxx                  2   Registration    from_name        xxxx xxxx
xxxxxxxx                  2   Registration    alternative-1    selected
```

etc.....

I've been trying to turn it into this:

```
submit_time | from_name   | from_email      | Alternative-1 |
xxxxxxxx       xxxx xxxx     xx@hotmail.com       selected  
xxxxxxxx       xxxx xxxx     xx@gmail.com
```

Now, I've tried with the following code:

```
select
  max(case WHEN field_name = 'submit_time' then field_value end) submit_time,
  max(case when field_name = 'from_name' then field_value end) from_name,
  max(case when field_name = 'from_email' then field_value end) from_email
from wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
```

However I get the classic "syntax error, missing operator" sign. Any ideas what I´m missing?

Comment: This is an unnatural to do in SQL, not least because a SQL table has columns that are of a well-defined type and rows of a fixed length.  Transposing columns into rows will cause problems in both respects.  However if this is really what you need to do, Google for "pivot tables".

Answer (score 0):

In Access this is accomplished with a "crosstab query". Try something like this

```sql
TRANSFORM First(field_value) AS FirstOffield_value
SELECT submit_time
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY submit_time
PIVOT field_name
```